# Creating a executable out of a library in CMake, and linking the library in another library

Tags: cmake

I am trying to link `foo-lib` library into another target `bar-lib` however doing the following results in an error.

> (add_executable):
> Cannot find source file: foo-lib

How can I create an executable out of a library and the same library can be linked into another target?

```
  add_library(foo-lib STATIC src/foo.cpp)
  add_executable(foo-ut foo-lib)
  target_include_directories(foo-ut PRIVATE include)
  target_link_libraries(foo-ut PUBLIC lib1 lib2)

  # second library that links foo-lib
  add_library(bar-lib STATIC src/bar.cpp)
  add_executable(bar-ut bar-lib)
  target_include_directories(bar-ut PRIVATE include)
  target_link_libraries(bar-ut PUBLIC foo-lib)
```

This worked the way I wanted but I am not sure if I should be adding `foo.cpp` for the `bar-ut` target

```
add_executable(bar-ut src/foo.cpp src/bar.cpp)
```

Comment: `add_executable` needs source files, not libraries.  Do you really not have any source files unique to `foo-ut`?

Comment: Shouldn't there really be a single source file?

Comment: I can't think of a non-trivial program I've worked on with only a single source file.  And even still, libraries and source files aren't interchangeable to cmake.

Comment: There's a similar syntax to what you've posted for `OBJECT` libraries, see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#object-libraries However for static and shared libs there's no equivalent. How would the behaviour of any other target linking `foo-lib` be different to `bar-ut` tough? After all it's `foo-lib` that contains the `main` function...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to question the design choices and what you need it for and if it is a good idea in any way. I will just provide you with a "scalable" way of doing this.

As the others pointed out `add_executable()` requires source files.

Now assuming that the source files that you use to create a static library contain a `main()` function. Then you can create (out of the same source files) an executable, by passing to the `add_executable` the same source files as you would to `add_library`.

As the program grows these would get lengthy, so what you should do is something that is no longer recommended by "CMake best practices" and that is to introduce a SOURCES variable. I.e.:

```
set(PROJECT_SOURCES source1.cpp source2.cpp source3.cpp)
set(PROJECT_HEADERS header1.h header2.h header3.h)

add_library(foo-lib STATIC ${PROJECT_SOURCES} ${PROJECT_HEADERS})
add_executable(foo-ut ${PROJECT_SOURCES} ${PROJECT_HEADERS}
```

As your program grows you would just add the respective files into the designated variables. Now as to possible improvements:

1. fabian mentioned a very good thing which is `OBJECT` libraries, since you are rebuilding the same files for both the executable and library you could just create an object library and link it. This would make it twice as fast (you only need to compile once).
2. Since these `SOURCES` are already once passed to some target, you could just get them from the target's properties via `get_target_properties(MY_SOURCES foo-lib SOURCES)` this would give you a variable `MY_SOURCES` that contains sources which are used by the target library.